# Hover doesn't change the color of my svg

Tags: css, colors, sass, hover, haml

I don't really know what's going on so i'll just put my pseudo code here, and if someone is nice enough to tell me what i do wrong i'll be really gratefull :)

**HAML**

```
.div
  %a{ href: link }
    .class-name= inline_svg('logo')
```

**SCSS**

```
.class-name:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

I dont get it because when i put an `opacity: 0.5;` it worked just fine, but not the color :/

ps: i don't have any `:link` or `:visited` in my real code, just saying because a lot of similar issues i found was about that.

Thank you :)

Comment: there is no `=` in CSS it should be `:`

Comment: it would be helpful if you post your code snippet with your query

Answer (score 1):

Try change your "=" to ":" in SCSS

```
color : blue;
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that svg needed to be filled, so the `color:` wouldn't have worked. I just needed to remove the `fill:` in my svg file and my css would have looked like that :

**CSS**

```
.class-name:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```